# WindowsPhone 8.1 WebView redirect

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm using in my application a WebView which loads a Url can redirect to the Win. App store and therefore the OS opens the Win. store app on the device or open another 3rd party application for SMS\Email\etc.

I didn't find out yet how to know whether there's a redirect on the WebView using its callback functions such as NavigationStarting or NavigationCompleted, does anyone have an idea?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

you can use  WebView.NavigationStarting event to get redirect url in webview.

XAML code:

```
<WebView x:Name="myWebView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" NavigationStarting="myWebView_NavigationStarting" />
```

Code behind (C#):

```
    private void myWebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        Uri uri = args.Uri;

        if(uri.ToString() == "url you want to compare")
        {   

            // work you want to do

        }
    }
```